# Is there a more efficient way of evaluating this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{x^2\ln(1+2x+x^2)}$$

This was a multiple choice question so it should not take me such a long time but the only way I see how to attack it is just L'Hôpital rule multiple times which is so inefficient as it keeps getting bigger and I'm more likely to make errors. The limit is $ \frac{1}{12} $ but I'm not sure how to show it. If there are any helpful tips on how to reduce the amount of calculation and make it simpler, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to know the Taylor expansions of $\sin(x)$, $\arctan(x)$, and $\ln(x)$?

Comment: No, we've never learned the expansions just a few trig identities special limits, limit properties, derivatives... very basic.

Comment: Do the special limits include things like $\frac{x - \sin x}{x^3}$ and $\frac{x-\arctan x}{x^3}$?

Comment: No, more like how the limit of sin(x) over x as x goes to 0 is 1. Again very basic. If I were to use Taylor expansions, is that something I just memorize and sub in for everything except the polynomials?

Comment: @cgug123 The Taylor series of $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, $e^x$, and $\log(1+x)$ at $x=0$ would probably be useful to memorize (they're all pretty simple, so just get some flashcards and you'll have 'em learned in a week or so).  For any other functions, it's usually sufficient to just calculate the first few terms explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

${\ln(1+2x+x^2)}=2\ln(1+x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (x+1)} x = 1$ therefore:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{x^2\ln(1+2x+x^2)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{2x^2\ln(1+x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{2x^3 \frac {\ln(1+x)} x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{2x^3}  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac  1 {\frac {\ln (x+1)}{x}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{2x^3}$

then use L'Hospital or, even better:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{2x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x + x -\arctan(x)}{2x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x} {2x^3} + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x - \arctan(x)} {2x^3}$

Comment: That's great okay, I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: One cannot simply replace $\log(1+x)$ with $x$.  They are not equal. Better is to write $\log(1+x)=x\left(1+O(x)\right)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I never said it can be replaced.

Comment: @EugenCovaci You explicitly did just that.

Comment: @Dr.MV See my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Use *Taylor's formula* and *equivalence of functions*:

- $\sin x-\arctan x= x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o(x^3)-\Bigl(x-\dfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)\Bigr)=\dfrac{x^3}6+o(x^3)\sim_0\dfrac{x^3}6$,
- $\ln(1+2x+x^2)=2\ln(1+x)=2x+o(x)\sim_02x$,
  so that $$\frac{\sin(x)-\arctan(x)}{x^2\ln(1+2x+x^2)}\sim_0\frac{\dfrac{x^3}6}{x^2\cdot 2x}=\frac1{12}.$$

Comment: This is the way to go!  +1

Answer (score 1):

If you know about the Taylor development approach, you should be aware that the first order approximation of both $\sin x$ and $\arctan x$ are $x$. As both functions are odd, there is no quadratic term, and the difference will feature a cubic term if the cubic coefficients differ. So you can expect a numerator approximated by $ax^3$.

In the denominator, $\ln(1+y)$ yields $y$, so that $\ln(1+2x+x^2)$ yields $2x+x^2$ and other terms (starting from quadratic). Together with the factor $x^2$, the approximation is $2x^3$.

Hence all you need are the third order Taylor coefficients, which you might know by heart to be $-1/3!$ and $-1/3$, giving the limit

$$\frac{-\frac16+\frac13}2.$$

---

If you don't know the coefficients, derive three times

$$\sin x\to\cos x\to-\sin x\to-\cos x,$$ giving the Taylor coefficient $-1/3!$

For the arc tangent,

$$\arctan x\to\frac1{1+x^2}.$$ You can continue to evaluate the derivatives but it is easier to use the geometric series summation formula to write

$$\frac1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+\cdots$$ which integrates as

$$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}3+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

$\ln(1+2x+x^2)=2\ln(1+x)\sim2x$.

Comment: cause $2\ln(1+x)\sim 2x (x\to 0)$.

Comment: You might consider being more precise by stating $\log(1+x)=x\left(1+O(x)\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - \arctan x}{x^{2}\log(1 + 2x + x^{2})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - \arctan x}{x^{2}\log(1 + x)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - \arctan x}{x^{2}\log(1 + x)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x - \arctan x}{x^{3}\cdot\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - \arctan x}{x^{3}}\notag
\end{align}
Now you can either use L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series approach (this one being easier) and easily get the answer as $1/12$.

Note that it is always a good idea to simplify the expression (whose limit is to be evaluated) via the use of identities (related to the functions involved) and standard limits like $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ before applying the technique of L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series.